# Summary page of multiple Jenkins item

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, rally

My environment: *Rally CA Agile Central*, *Jenkins*, *Bitbucket*

Below is the project page that I have in *Jenkins*.

- Code Coverage report done with *Gocvr*
- *Cppcheck*
- Unit Test with *GoogleTest*

[image]

I have a project that is divided among several *Bitbucket* repositories. Each of those repositories are a *Jenkins Freestyle* project. Each *Jenkins Freestyle* project will then have its own *CPPCheck*, Unit Test and code coverage report.

My question is if there is a way to summarize all those metrics together so it is easier during our meeting to have 1 place to go where to see all those Jenkins jobs in our project. Even see a general trend for the whole project (code coverage is going up / down, etc) and not just for each Jenkins Freestyle project individually.

I'm quite open to where these metrics can live. But, since we already are using CA-Rally and Jenkins and a lot of plugins/hooks are already developed, there is maybe something that already exists that could fulfill my needs.